# Brand new CLR Class Library project won't build: missing MSCOREE.lib

Tags: c++-cli, clr, visual-studio-2019

Using the latest Visual Studio 2019 version, a brand new project will not build:

```
fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'MSCOREE.lib'
```

I have tried to re-install Visual Studio but that didn't change anything unfortunately.

These components have been selected by the installer but apparently it's not enough:

- MSVC v142 - VS 2019 C++ x64/x86 build tools (v14.24)
- Windows 10 SDK (10.0.18362.0)
- C++/CLI support for v142 build tools (14.24)

**Question:**

Are there any tricks to get *CLR Class Library (.NET Framework)* projects to build ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution:

Apparently, no matter what framework version you will target, the `$(NETFXKitsDir)Lib\um\x86` macro will always point to `C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.7.2\lib\um\x86`.

Now here's the problem, even though you install 4.7.2 SDK in Visual Studio Installer, this file is nowhere to be seen.

But if you download [.NET Framework 4.7.2 Developer Pack Offline Installer](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/visual-studio-sdks) and press the Repair button, it gets correctly installed and a brand new project will build succesfully.

Alternatively:

Re-installing VS also fixes the issue ...

Comment: Is your project using 4.7.2? My project is using 4.6.2, so I installed 4.6.2 developer pack, but it didn't fix it for me...

Comment: Yes it was 4.7.2, I'd suggest you to try in a VM, it appears that the order in which those dev packs are installed seems to affect correct behavior -> trial and error unless MS fixes it.

Comment: I could solve the problem by installing .Net Framework 4.7.2 SDK in the Visual Studio Installer. Before, I only had 4.7.8 installed.